Log4j2 Logger Class with 2 seperate Log Files
im currently trying to create a LocalLogger Class which i can use in my Project to log stuff.
General Idea is:
Logs from TRACE to INFO -> infoLog.log
Logs from WARN to FATAL -> errorLog.log
ALL LOGS IN CONSOLE
I want to set the info and error Log Path dynamically from a Config Class in my Project.
Thats why i wanted to use the programmatically provided configuration.
I tried out stuff, but currently all i get are FATAL logs, in console and both log files. No matter what i do.
So basically the structure is like this:
public class LocalLogger {

    private final Logger logger;

    private final Class<?> logClass;

    private Configuration config;
    private final Date startTime;


    public LocalLogger(Configuration config, Class<?> logClass) {
        this.config = config;
        this.logClass = logClass;
        this.startTime = new Date();

        configureLogger();
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(logClass);

        logInfo("Starting Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss").format(startTime));
        logInfo("ErrorLogFile set to -> " + config.getErrorLogFile());
    }

    public LocalLogger(Class<?> logClass) {
        this.logClass = logClass;
        this.startTime = new Date();

        configureLogger();
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(logClass);

        logInfo("Starting Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss").format(startTime));
    }

    /***
     * Sets Logging to configured LogFile/ErrorLogFile and LogLevel in xml-configurationFile
     */
    private void configureLogger() {
        /* this is the magic part, where i need help (when config is not set / null -> just use "infoLog.log" and "errorLog.log" */
    }


    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logInfo(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    } // info

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logWarning(String message) {
        logger.warn(message);
    } // warn

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logFine(String message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logFinest(String message) {
        logger.trace(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Handles truncated stack trace logging via Log4j Logging
     *
     * @param key unique String value (e.g. file path)
     * @param message individual log message
     * @param exception the exception to log with max stack trace length
     *
     */
    public void logSevere(String key, String message, Exception exception) {
        //TODO special exception Handling?

        String msg = key + ":" + message;

        logger.fatal(msg);
    } // error

I tried it like that:
private void configureLogger() {
        String infoLog = config != null && config.getLogFile() != null && config.getLogFile().isEmpty() ? config.getLogFile() : "infoLog.log";
        String errorLog = config != null && config.getErrorLogFile() != null && config.getErrorLogFile().isEmpty() ? config.getErrorLogFile() : "errorLog.log";
        String logLevel = config != null && config.getLogLevel() != null && config.getLogLevel().isEmpty() ? config.getLogLevel() : "TRACE";

        
        try (LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true)) {
            ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

            
            builder.setStatusLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN);
            builder.setConfigurationName("DynamicConfig");

            
            AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("Console", "CONSOLE")
                    .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
            consoleAppender.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                    .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level: %msg%n"));
            builder.add(consoleAppender);

            
            AppenderComponentBuilder fileInfoAppender = builder.newAppender("InfoFile", "FILE")
                    .addAttribute("fileName", infoLog)
                    .addAttribute("append", "true");
            fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                    .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level: %msg%n"));
            fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                    .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO));
            builder.add(fileInfoAppender);

            
            AppenderComponentBuilder fileErrorAppender = builder.newAppender("ErrorFile", "FILE")
                    .addAttribute("fileName", errorLog)
                    .addAttribute("append", "true");
            fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                    .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level: %msg%n"));
            fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                    .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN));
            builder.add(fileErrorAppender);

            
            RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.getLevel(logLevel));
            rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
            rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InfoFile"));
            rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ErrorFile"));
            builder.add(rootLogger);

            
            org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration configuration = builder.build();
            context.start(configuration);  
        } 
    }

Test Class was this:
public class TestingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalLogger logger = new LocalLogger(TestingMain.class);

        logger.logInfo("Test");
        logger.logSevere("Test", "123", new Exception());
    }
}

OUTPUT:
2024-08-28T08:31:57.614119700Z main WARN No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
10:31:57.640 [main] FATAL de.tde.ecm.vp.fp8.start.TestingMain - Test:123

But then why does the logInfo also doesnt get logged?

here's a link on logger inheritance and appender additivity Should be helpful to you

Now i get all Debug Stuff from log4j bcs i added the jvm arg, but INFO is still not logged lol. Everything else but info is logged now

Text too long, here is a link to a txt: https://jmp.sh/s/N8mmYlv8zJU85i2SMqJo

Note: LogManager.getContext(true) usually gives you the wrong logger context, the parameter should always be false. The try-with-resources should not be used with LoggerContext, since it closes the logger context you just configured.

Ok, so I went through your configuration and went through the log4j wiki since yesterday. The root cause is that when using a ConfigurationBuilder, you need to initialize the builder using the Configurator.initialize methods otherwise a default configuration is used for logging.
public class misc {
    private final Logger logger;

    public misc() {
        configureLogger();
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        misc m = new misc();
        m.logFine("fine");
        m.logInfo("info");
        m.logWarning("warning");
    }

    private void configureLogger() {
        String infoLog = "infoLog.log";
        String errorLog = "errorLog.log";
        String logLevel = "TRACE";


        try (LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true)) {
            ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

            builder.setStatusLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN);
            builder.setConfigurationName("DynamicConfig");

            LayoutComponentBuilder standard
                    = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
            standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");


            AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("Console", "Console")
                    .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
            consoleAppender.add(standard);
            builder.add(consoleAppender);


            AppenderComponentBuilder fileInfoAppender = builder.newAppender("InfoFile", "File")
                    .addAttribute("fileName", infoLog)
                    .addAttribute("append", "true");
            fileInfoAppender.add(standard);
            fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                    .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO));
            builder.add(fileInfoAppender);


            AppenderComponentBuilder fileErrorAppender = builder.newAppender("ErrorFile", "File")
                    .addAttribute("fileName", errorLog)
                    .addAttribute("append", "true");
            fileErrorAppender.add(standard);
            fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                    .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN));
            builder.add(fileErrorAppender);


            RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.getLevel(logLevel));
            rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
            rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InfoFile"));
            rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ErrorFile"));
            builder.add(rootLogger);

            var ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build()); // <--
//            org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration configuration = builder.build();
//            context.start(configuration);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logInfo(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    } // info

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logWarning(String message) {
        logger.warn(message);
    } // warn

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logFine(String message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logFinest(String message) {
        logger.trace(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Handles truncated stack trace logging via Log4j Logging
     *
     * @param key unique String value (e.g. file path)
     * @param message individual log message
     * @param exception the exception to log with max stack trace length
     *
     */
    public void logSevere(String key, String message, Exception exception) {
        //TODO special exception Handling?

        String msg = key + ":" + message;

        logger.fatal(msg);
    } // error
}

Also, while perusing the Log4j2 wiki, it seems the try-with resources wasn't really used, so at the end of the day, I removed it to end up with the following:
    private void configureLogger() {
        String infoLog = "infoLog.log";
        String errorLog = "errorLog.log";
        String logLevel = "TRACE";


        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN);
        builder.setConfigurationName("DynamicConfig");

        LayoutComponentBuilder standard
                = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
        standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");


        AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("Console", "Console")
                .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        consoleAppender.add(standard);
        builder.add(consoleAppender);


        AppenderComponentBuilder fileInfoAppender = builder.newAppender("InfoFile", "File")
                .addAttribute("fileName", infoLog)
                .addAttribute("append", "true");
        fileInfoAppender.add(standard);
        fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO));
        builder.add(fileInfoAppender);


        AppenderComponentBuilder fileErrorAppender = builder.newAppender("ErrorFile", "File")
                .addAttribute("fileName", errorLog)
                .addAttribute("append", "true");
        fileErrorAppender.add(standard);
        fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN));
        builder.add(fileErrorAppender);


        RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.getLevel(logLevel));
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InfoFile"));
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ErrorFile"));
        builder.add(rootLogger);

        var ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    }

but, as I mentioned in the comments, your use of rootlogger for everything means that your infoLog.log will look like:
2024-08-29 10:40:51,816 [main] INFO : info
2024-08-29 10:40:51,820 [main] WARN : warning
2024-08-29 10:42:16,552 [main] INFO : info
2024-08-29 10:42:16,554 [main] WARN : warning
2024-08-29 10:43:04,961 [main] INFO : info
2024-08-29 10:43:04,963 [main] WARN : warning
2024-08-29 10:43:52,780 [main] INFO : info
2024-08-29 10:43:52,782 [main] WARN : warning
2024-08-29 10:54:20,617 [main] INFO : info
2024-08-29 10:54:20,619 [main] WARN : warning

Then, you need to configure new loggers for your specific purposes like so:
private final Logger logger;
private final Logger elogger;
private final Logger ilogger;

public misc() {
    configureLogger();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(this);
    elogger = LogManager.getLogger("errorLogger");
    ilogger = LogManager.getLogger("infoLogger");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    misc m = new misc();
    m.logFine("fine");
    m.logInfo("info");
    m.logWarning("warning");
}

private void configureLogger() {
    String infoLog = "infoLog.log";
    String errorLog = "errorLog.log";
    String logLevel = "TRACE";


    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

    builder.setStatusLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN);
    builder.setConfigurationName("DynamicConfig");

    LayoutComponentBuilder standard
            = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
    standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");


    AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("Console", "Console")
            .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    consoleAppender.add(standard);
    builder.add(consoleAppender);


    AppenderComponentBuilder fileInfoAppender = builder.newAppender("InfoFile", "File")
            .addAttribute("fileName", infoLog)
            .addAttribute("append", "true");
    fileInfoAppender.add(standard);
    fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
            .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO));
    builder.add(fileInfoAppender);


    AppenderComponentBuilder fileErrorAppender = builder.newAppender("ErrorFile", "File")
            .addAttribute("fileName", errorLog)
            .addAttribute("append", "true");
    fileErrorAppender.add(standard);
    fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
            .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN));
    builder.add(fileErrorAppender);


    RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.getLevel(logLevel));
    rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
    builder.add(rootLogger);

    var errorLogger = builder.newLogger("errorLogger", Level.WARN);
    errorLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ErrorFile"));
    builder.add(errorLogger);

    var infoLogger = builder.newLogger("infoLogger", Level.INFO);
    infoLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InfoFile"));
    builder.add(infoLogger);

    var ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
}

/**
 * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
 *
 * @param message message to log
 */
public void logInfo(String message) {
    ilogger.info(message);
} // info

/**
 * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
 *
 * @param message message to log
 */
public void logWarning(String message) {
    elogger.warn(message);
} // warn

/**
 * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
 *
 * @param message message to log
 */
public void logFine(String message) {
    logger.debug(message);
} // debug

/**
 * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
 *
 * @param message message to log
 */
public void logFinest(String message) {
    logger.trace(message);
} // debug

/**
 * Handles truncated stack trace logging via Log4j Logging
 *
 * @param key unique String value (e.g. file path)
 * @param message individual log message
 * @param exception the exception to log with max stack trace length
 *
 */
public void logSevere(String key, String message, Exception exception) {
    //TODO special exception Handling?

    String msg = key + ":" + message;

    elogger.fatal(msg);
} // error


Thank you bro. Ur my savior
But i used the try-with-resources statement bcs i always got a warning when i used Configurator.initialize
